# CSS селектор для поиска атрибута src

Tags: javascript, css, electron

Есть такой элемент

`script src="file:///D:\Projects\Electron\Logist SPA\app\clientRegistration.js">`

Нужно найти его селектором по вот этой вот части "app\clientRegistration.js".

Пробовал так

```
document.querySelector('[src$="app\clientRegistration.js"]'), и так 
document.querySelector('[src$="app/clientRegistration.js"]'), и так 
document.querySelector('[src$="app/\clientRegistration.js"]'), и так
document.querySelector('[src$="app\\clientRegistration.js"]')  

// результат одинаковый NULL. Находит только так   
document.querySelector('[src$="clientRegistration.js"]').
```

Вопрос как экранировать слэш чтобы поиск оказался успешным?

Comment: Должно быть вот так `document.querySelector('[src$="app/clientRegistration.js"]')`. Возможно, в момент поиска элемента еще не существует?

Comment: пропиши ему `id`, делов-то

Comment: Существует, так как я добавляю скрипт динамически и это селектор как раз нужен чтобы чтобы понимать добавлен этот скрипт или еще нет

Comment: Добавлять  id не вариант

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Селектор `document.querySelector('[src$="app/clientRegistration.js"]')` 100% рабочий.

Возможно, потому что у вас обратный слеш. Попробуйте вот так  `document.querySelector('[src$="app\\\\clientRegistration.js"]')`

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('[src$="2.1.1/jquery.min.js"]'));
console.log(document.querySelector('[src$="2.1.0\\\\jquery.min.js"]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0\jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо огромное. Пробовал с 3-мя слешами, но до 4 не додумался((

Comment: @user185252 Получается так. `\\\\` - нужны, что бы в итоговой строчке было 2 слэша `\\`, затем эти два слэша - это один экранированный слеш для селектора.